# Cross Account AWS redshift connection- connection timeout

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am trying to connect AWS redshift in different account with **AWS glue** setup in another account. I have setup the cross account connectivity via IAM roles trust entity and its working fine.
I am able to get the Redshift cluster credentials via STS. But after creating the boto3 client for redshift using the temporary credentials and while creating the connection, getting below error.
`InterfaceError: ('communication error', TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out'))`.

Below is my setup.

[image]

Below is my simple code.

```
assume_role_response=_get_sts_credentials()
    if 'Credentials' in assume_role_response:
        assumed_session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=assume_role_response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            aws_secret_access_key=assume_role_response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
            aws_session_token=assume_role_response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

    client = assumed_session.client('redshift')

    logger.info('Getting temp Redshift credentials')
    try:
        redshift_temp_credentials = client.get_cluster_credentials(DbUser=redshift_user_name,
                                                                   DbName=redshift_database,
                                                                   ClusterIdentifier=redshift_cluster_id,
                                                                   AutoCreate=False)

        print('temp username is {} and password is {}'.format(redshift_temp_credentials['DbUser'],
                                                              redshift_temp_credentials['DbPassword']))

        connection = redshift_connector.connect(host=redshift_host,
                                                database=redshift_database,
                                                user=redshift_temp_credentials['DbUser'],
                                                password=redshift_temp_credentials['DbPassword'])
        return connection
```

Comment: What are you trying to connect from where? Are you running your code on an Amazon EC2 instance in Account-A, wanting to connect to an Amazon Redshift database in Account-B? What is the networking connectivity between the two? Is there a VPC Peering connection, or is the Redshift database configured as `Publicly accessible = Yes`? Why do you think they should be able to communicate with each other?

Comment: I have tagged the flow architecture in the question.